# Blank screen after Ubuntu logo appears when booting wubi

Tags: boot, wubi

I tried wubi but it didn't start up after the first boot. On the second boot up option came up to select Ubuntu or Windows 7. I choose Ubuntu but only the logo appeared and then after that a blank black screen.

How can I uninstall it without affecting Windows 7?

My processor is Intel i3 64-bit but wubi downloaded for amd 64-bit. Was that the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can safely uninstall through the Control Panel. Go to Add/remove programs, find the `Ubuntu`  entry and double click it.

The `amd64` refers to the standard, not the chip manufacturer. It works fine on an intel 64 bit CPU.

Most likely you are having problems with the intel GPU. There are some bug reports on blank screens at startup e.g. [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/752165). If you want to try and solve it please update your question with your computer brand/model/graphics card(s).